# Как получить содержимое таблицы с html

Tags: java, html

Имеется сайт с таблицей, аналогичный такому https://www.parimatch.by/live.html

Имеется код на Java, который получает код html страницы и выводит его в консоль. Я реализовал его через **Scanner**.
Но, на данном сайте, если я не ошибаюсь, данные таблицы заполняются с помощью JavaScript. И обычный код, вроде этого, для получения html страницы, данных таблицы не получит:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String content = null;
    URLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        connection =  new         
    URL("https://www.parimatch.by/live.html").openConnection();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
        scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z");
        content = scanner.next();
    }catch ( Exception ex ) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(content);
}
}
```

**Такой вопрос, как более целесообразно реализовать получение данных с таблицы:**

1) Организовать средствами Java скачивание html страницы и потом спарсить нужные данные

2) Обойтись без скачивания html страницы

Причем, что обновлять данные таблицы придется каждые 3 секунды.

Comment: так jsoup вам не подходит?

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с Muzaffar Rasulov, тут нужно использовать jsoup, на счет второго пункта: "Обойтись без скачивания html страницы" - а как еще то данные получит приложение? Выход только делать запросы API.
+ сайт заблочен.